# WPF fit row to grid width with auto sized columns

Tags: wpf, grid, width, autosize

I have a problem with fitting grid row to parent grid width. So the code is (table header):

```
<Grid Height="Auto" Margin="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" >Word</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >Class</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" >Match case</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" >Regular expression</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" >Commands</Label>
</Grid>
```

The problem is: if all columns based on `Width="Auto"` the resulting rows will not fit parent grid. I know that I can fix this by setting `Width="*"` on one of the columns, but it's not what I want.

I need auto size on all columns with fitting to grid width (which can be much bigger then calculated auto-size of a row). How can I archive that?

Answer (score 0):

Use Viewbox if you don't want to set Width="Auto", it is properly fitting the grid.

```
 <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid Height="Auto" Margin="20">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" >Word</Label>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >Class</Label>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" >Match case</Label>
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" >Regular expression</Label>
            <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" >Commands</Label>
        </Grid>
 </Viewbox>
```

Comment: But Viewbox scaling content instead of resizing width, it leads to giant font size when window maximized

Comment: Best option for this is to set Width="*"(asterisk) for all ColumnDefinition. I.e      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />. Other option is you have to set fixed width for label according to the windows size. Divide width equally for all label according to window size. But this can create issue in different screen resolution. I would suggest you to set Width="*" for all ColumnDefinition. By setting width = "*" it will equally divide space for all columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `SharedSizeGroup` property to share sizing properties between several different `ColumnDefinition`s that belongs to different `Grid`s: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx

```
<Grid Height="Auto" Margin="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="a" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="b" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="c" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="d" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="e" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" >Word</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >Class</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" >Match case</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" >Regular expression</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" >Commands</Label>
</Grid>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="a" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="b" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="c" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="d" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="e" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap">Some long word.....</TextBlock>
    <!-- -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have the only one Grid element, why do I need to use SharedSizeGroup? By "parent" I meant Grid control, which contains rows and columns - just as in my sample and nothing more.

Comment: So you have one Grid with a few Labels and you want to do what exactly?

Comment: I want that labels to fit all width of Grid, for now labels occupy only left part of it - and huge space remains empty.

Comment: Left part? There is a Label in each column, isn't it? I don't understand your issue. You have a Grid with 5 columns that have an equal width. Each column contains a Label. Again: What is your issue?